# ¿Cómo parsear una cadena de tiempo con Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Tengo una cadena de este tipo: `"18:00:00"` y necesito parsearla con Swift 3 para poder mostrarla en un formato más estilizado, por ejemplo: `"6:00 pm"`. He usado `DateFormatter` con el formato `"hh:mm:ss"` pero no lo convierte.

```
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

if let tiempo = timeFormatter.string(from: "18:00:00")
{
    print(tiempo)
}
else
{
    print("No se pudo")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato que deberías usar en este caso es `"HH:mm:ss"`.

Luego, para convertir al nuevo formato puedes usar otro *formatter*:

```
let toFormatter = DateFormatter()
toFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
print(toFormatter.string(from: tiempo))
```

La salida para este ejemplo es:

> 6:00 PM

Los formatos están documentados en la [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4) (en inglés).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funcionó perfecto, nunca había trabajado con fechas y tiempos, hoy aprendí algo nuevo :)